# How do I fetch an object that is not part of an relationship

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

Lets say we have two entities Department and Employees with a one-to-many relationship.

How do I fetch all employees who are not part of a selected Department?

Answer (score 2):

Create a fetch request for the Employee entity and add a predicate that says "self.department NOT like %@", passing in the selected department as the parameter.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for. I have not seen any examples in the documentation using two arguments.